# Words containing "катя"

Tags: перевод

My friend has "КАТЯ" tattooed on him. It is the name of his ex-girlfriend. He wants to change the tattoo and make it into a longer word that has "КАТЯ" as a part of it.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm... This isn't an easy one. I seriously doubt it's possible to find a replacement that would content-rich enough to be used as a tattoo. The only "Катящийся"="Rolling" comes to mind but this would be a bit weird to have exposed on your skin..

Comment: And you can add: Катящийся в ад или Катящийся к чёрту. Sounds cool to me for a tattoo. It's like "Highway to hell".

Answer (score 18):

```
$ aspell -l ru dump master | aspell -l ru expand | grep -o '\w*катя\w*'
```

окатят
укатят
окатятся
укатятся
откатят
откатятся
докатят
докатятся
катя
катят
катясь
катятся
катящий
катящая
катящею
катящее
катящего
катящей
катящем
катящему
катящую
катящие
катящих
катящим
катящими
катящийся
катящаяся
катящеюся
катящееся
катящегося
катящейся
катящемся
катящемуся
катящиеся
катящихся
катящимися
катящимся
катящуюся
накатят
накатятся
подкатят
подкатятся
покатят
покатятся
перекатят
прикатят
прокатят
перекатятся
прикатятся
прокатятся
раскатят
раскатятся
скатят
скатятся
вкатят
выкатят
вкатятся
выкатятся
закатят
закатятся

Comment: wow, UNIX way :) nice!

Answer (score 3):

Consider making `ж` out of `к`.
But I'm still in doubt what reasonable words can be made out of `жатя`
`ржатя` - [nonce word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonce_word) that I've just coined. It means: "*something funny you want to make out of your ex-girlfriend's name*".

Answer (score 3):

As you see from other answers it's not easy to make something with "КАТЯ". The best variant I can think of is "**КАТЯРА**" the misspelled form of "котяра" which is derivative from "cat". "Котяра" can mean "big, full-grown cat" ("здоровый котяра", here "здоровый" means "big") or "seasoned, experienced cat" ("матёрый котяра"). Multitran.ru [gives other translations](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=%EA%EE%F2%FF%F0%E0): "tomcat", "moggy". Better to use it with other misspelled word(s), to clarify that it's misspelling. For example: "ЗДАРОВЫЙ КАТЯРА","БАЛЬШОЙ КАТЯРА","МОТЁРЫЙ КАТЯРА","ЛЮБВЕАБИЛЬНЫЙ КАТЯРА". Or even better to make drawing of some big cat like lion or tiger with title "КАТЯРА".
It's not that good variant, but I don't see anything better other than to delete the tattoo.

Comment: только "мАтёрый катяра"

Comment: @borisbn You missed the point about intentional misspelling

Comment: Yes, мОтёрый кАтяра is a great combination, with A and O flipped to find themselves in wrong places.

Answer (score 1):

I have a rather grim suggestion: he can add periods: "КАТ.Я." "Кат" is an anachronism for "executioner", so it would mean "Executioner. Me."

Answer (score 0):

Some rational coinage: "НАКАТЯРА" = a booze artist.

Comment: Sounds suspicious. Катяра sounds like misspelled котяра - a big male cat.

Comment: "Котяра" is a derivation from "кот". "Накатяра" derives from "накатывать (to booze)".

Comment: I understand the link to "накат", but "artist" is not present in the word itself. The owner of such tatoo would have to make also a tatoo with a link to your post for an explanation of the meaning of "накатяра".

Answer (score 0):

For me, "КАТЯ" or Katya in Romanized word is a good name to put in there. It is sound unique to me but if I suggest to put it longer, I don't know if that his girl's nickname or full name. If that's a nickname, better to put her full name.  I have Russian friend have a nickname "КАТЯ", her name is Katyusha.

If it is her name, try to put sweet word on her name like "Cute Katya", "Sweet Katya" etc. in Russian word. As on ex- one, try to put something inspiring.

Comment: You are missing the point. The owner of the tatoo wants to make it to look like it's not a girls name at all.

Comment: ahh.. ok.. sorry.. as the sentence said, "He wants to change the tattoo and make it into a longer word that has "КАТЯ" as a part of it." "Part of it" word is like Katya word are still in there and I try to suggest that if he want to make it longer. So maybe I miss out what this sentence means.

Comment: BTW, FYI, Katyusha is not a name but a diminutive form of the name Ekaterina: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katyusha.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "катящиеся камни" (rolling stones)?

Comment: I have no idea why my answer appeared twice - the short version was rejected, so I added the postscriptum to make it longer and resubmitted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "катящиеся камни"?

.....

Answer (score 0):

Nearly as Vitaly Sazanovich has proposed - slight modification could be applied. 'K' letter can be changed to 'B' (russian 'v'). It is not so straightforward as modifying it into 'Ж', but still could be done, result will be styled as ancient script [image: see 5th letter here]. Why would you make it? Because 'ВАТЯ' could be found in some cool expressions like

1) based on verb caught/grabbed e.g. '[МЕНЯ] НЕ СХВАТЯТ' '[I] WON'T GET CAUGHT'

2) based on verb 'be beaten' in quite a macho form e.g. 'ВРАГИ ОТХВАТЯТ'/'ВРАГИ ВЫХВАТЯТ' = 'enemies will be beaten'

3) based on specific form of noun 'bed', however I don't think any girl would like such on her bf :) e.g. "BED JUMPER" "СКАКУН ПО КРОВАТЯМ" (this one may be polished further)

4) something based on form of verb catch in meaning of spreading - ПОДХВАТЯТ, that can be used in some formula e.g. 'Я СКАЖУ/НАЧНУ - ДРУЗЬЯ ПОДХВАТЯТ' 'I SHALL SAY/START AND FRIENDS SHALL SPREAD (CARRY ON, HELP, follow me/my example)'